# How can I create the visit website button on facebook app cover page?

Tags: facebook

When I create an app on facebook, It just shows one button: go to app. What I want is a button called "visit website". Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `App category` you've chosen when you created the app, and if you've set the URL of your app in the `Website with Facebook Login` input.

If you've chosen "Games" in the `App category` then the button would say "Start game" or something like that.

Comment: I set the URL of my app in the Website with Facebook Login input, and choose the "Entertainment" in the APP category, it just show the "Go to app". SO which app category should I choose? Thank you